# Error Checking XML DOM XMLDOC

Tags: xml, delphi, dom, error-handling, xmldocument

how to check if the XML has error before or after loading it in the XMLDocuments?
i would like to trap that error so that it will not proceed. not to use "Try Except"
common error are "cut, currupted, invalid symbols etc". any idea?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520572/how-check-if-a-xml-file-if-well-formed-using-delphi

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XML DOM validator, or you can use the functions.  Alternatively, I found a very easy-to-follow, step-by-step tutorial, provided by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379.  It tells you how to validate your XML documents in visual studio, and I was able to run it against the example code at RRUZs' link.